# Using Dask map_partition with Series StringMethods gives me a memory error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

My chickens.csv file has around 140 columns and 1.5 million entries 
 it's about 1.1 gigabytes on disk.
When I run the code below:

```
def main():
    frame = dd.read_csv("Z:\\food\\chickens.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8", engine='python', dtype="object")
    print(frame)

    for field in frame.columns:
         frame[field] = frame[field].map_partitions(lambda value:value.str.slice(start=1,stop=-1))

    frame = frame.set_index("ID_NUM", drop=False, npartitions='auto')
    print(frame)

main()
```

I get this memory error

```
  File "F:/Desktop/food-processing/tester.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/Desktop/food-processing/tester.py", line 20, in main
    frame = frame.set_index("ID_NUM", drop=False, npartitions='auto')
  File "F:\Desktop\food-processing\chicken_farm\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 3557, in set_index
    **kwargs
  File "F:\Desktop\food-processing\chicken_farm\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\shuffle.py", line 79, in set_index
    divisions, sizes, mins, maxes, optimize_graph=False
  ...
  ...
  File "F:\Desktop\food-processing\chicken_farm\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 771, in copy
    values = values.copy()
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 40.7 MiB for an array with shape (143, 37273) and data type object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `map_partitions` so many times, you can call it just once and do the loop within your tasks

replace

```
for field in frame.columns:
     frame[field] = frame[field].map_partitions(lambda value:value.str.slice(start=1,stop=-1))
```

with

```
def slicethem(frame):
    for field in frame.columns:
        frame[field] = frame[field].str.slice(start=1, stop=-1)
    return frame
frame = frame.map_partitions(slicethem)
```

This ends up with a much smaller graph and fewer intermediaries.

Comment: It finishes now. Thanks

Comment: I've seen visualize() but Is there anyway to get numerical task graph info ? I'm looking for something that for example prints the amount of tasks and some ballpark metric for how much resources those tasks will require?

Comment: You can look at `frame.dask` for the graph. You cannot know the resource usage ahead of time (because python). With the distributed scheduler, you can monitor workers current usage. The scheduler does look at the size of outputs, but that's not what you are probably after.